# Using input to determine which array to call

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm still getting the basics of Ruby, and just completed an assignment to recreate the Tower of Hanoi. I would REALLY like to condense my code, but for that, I would need to call upon a specific array based on the users input. For example:

```
 Stack_1=[5,4,3] 
 Stack_2=[5,2,1] 
 Stack_3=[5]

 puts "Please select a tower" 
 tower_select=gets.chomp.to_i
 puts "Please select where you'd like to move" 
 tower_move=gets.chomp.to_i

 if Stack_{tower_select}[-1] < Stack_{tower_move}[-1]   
   Stack_{tower_move} << Stack_{tower_select}[-1]   
   Stack_{tower_select}.delete_at(-1) 
 else puts "ERROR: Invalid move"
 end
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It's important to use proper Ruby syntax when asking a question about code you've written. `Stack_{tower_select}[-1]` isn't valid and results in "NoMethodError: undefined method `Stack_' for main:Object". See "[mcve]" and the linked page.

Answer (score 1):

Put your stacks in an Array or Hash and everything gets easier. This uses a Hash (they look scary at first, but are a breeze to handle):

```
stacks = {1 => [5,4,3],
          2 => [5,2,1],
          3 => [5]}  # a Hash

 puts "Please select a tower" 
 tower_select = gets.chomp.to_i
 puts "Please select where you'd like to move" 
 tower_move = gets.chomp.to_i

 if stacks[tower_select][-1] < stacks[tower_move][-1]   
   stacks[tower_move] << stacks[tower_select][-1]   
   stacks[tower_select].delete_at(-1)
   #or just: stacks[tower_move] << stacks[tower_select].pop 
 else puts "ERROR: Invalid move"
 end

p stacks
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it *is* possible using Ruby's reflection methods:

```
 if const_get(:"Stack_#{tower_select}")[-1] < const_get(:"Stack_#{tower_move}")[-1]   
   const_get(:"Stack_#{tower_move}") << const_get(:"Stack_#{tower_select}")[-1]   
   const_get(:"Stack_#{tower_select}").delete_at(-1) 
 else
   puts 'ERROR: Invalid move'
 end
```

But you *do not want to do this*. Seriously. Don't. Just … don't.

*Whenever* you feel the need to have variables (or in this case constants, but it doesn't matter) named like `foo_1`, `foo_2`, etc. there is a better solution. You know, Ruby already has a data structure that you can put things into that you want to access by index. They are called arrays, and you already know about them since you actually use them in your code already:

```
stacks = [[5, 4, 3], [5, 2, 1], [5]]

puts 'Please select a tower'
tower_select = gets.to_i - 1 # somehow, "normal" humans count from 1 …
puts "Please select where you'd like to move" 
tower_move = gets.to_i - 1

if stacks[tower_select].last < stacks[tower_move].last   
  stacks[tower_move] << stacks[tower_select].pop   
else
  puts 'ERROR: Invalid move'
end
```

[You might notice a couple of additional fixes I put in there. Your code wasn't wrong, but this is more idiomatic.]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much for your help!